# Why does Clojure have the promise deliver function?

Tags: clojure, promise

In Clojure, `promise` objects implement `clojure.lang.IFn`, and invoking the promise with a single argument fulfills the promise. That's how `deliver` is implemented:<sup>[[source]](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L7047)</sup>

```
(defn deliver
  "Delivers the supplied value to the promise, releasing any pending
  derefs. A subsequent call to deliver on a promise will have no effect."
  {:added "1.1"
   :static true}
  [promise val] (promise val))
```

If `(deliver x y)` is just a level of indirection over `(x y)`, why use `deliver` at all?

I'm assuming this is supposed to help disambiguate promises from functions in some way—but the same argument could apply to using some promise-specific function to read from a promise rather than using the general `deref` function for that.

Comment: Probably to allow for the implementation to be changed in future.

Comment: To rephrase @Lee’s comment, `deliver` is the documented public API, the direct fn call is the implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's syntactic sugar to make code like this look nice:

```
(-> url
    download
    extract-value
    (deliver consumer)
```

The deliver function used to have the behavior of ensuring that if you where the second caller to it an exception would be thrown. It was changed in 2011 and now the later calls are simply ignored.

Promises always had the same behavior if called as a function and if called from deliver, the function deliver only filled the roll of making something a little different look a little different. These days T would still use it to communicate with my future self

Comment: The bit about the extra functionality disappearing back in 2011 cleared this up for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`deref` is a lot less general than the function-call mechanism. When you see something deref'd, you know it is fetching some value from somewhere. When you see `(f x)` you really have no idea what is happening if you don't already know what `f` is: it could do anything at all. `deliver` gives you more context.